# How to color connected components in binary image using opencv in c++

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I have calculated anomaly image from grayscale image. The result is in the image below:

[anomaly image with 5 anomalies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qM66.jpg)

once I got result above I want to colorize anomalies with: 
1. red color, if the anomaly area is greater than 10 px or 
2. green color, if the anomaly area is les than or equal to 10 px.

For calculating properties of anomalies I used opencv function ''connectedComponentsWithStats()''. I can see that function calculated for me centroids of anomalies and also areas..

How can I now color all detected connected components?? In matlab I was using comething like pixelIdList to address each connected component and repmat(1,1,3) to extend binary image to RGB and then set up one of the chanels to ''true'', but how can I address all connected components in c++ ??

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The community needs a [mcve] to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do the same thing in OpenCV. Change the channels of your output image to 3 (RGB/BGR). Then you can loop through each pixel and set it to the colour you want based on their other criteria like (area, centroid) in a nested if loop.

Comment: Can you provide me with some code : How can I loop trought each calculated connected components? How can I color areas that are greater than 10 with red and connected components that are les than 10 pixel area with green? How to address connected components?